# Ax 2012 aif catching warnings

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I created an AIF web service in ax. I have a vb.net application that calls the aif web service to insert data into the general journal.  Now when an error occurs i catch it in vb and it returns the error which is fine. What i want to do is also catch the warning messages. Usually what happens , is if a line is getting entered and its a wrong dimension, it returns a warning message and an error. but i only get the error.  So the question is how can i either catch and retrieve the warning message in ax along with the error and return it to my application.  Basically need to get it from the exception list in ax.

Comment: Check this link https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/35246

Comment: If you want to customize then this will help http://axdevnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/aif-exception-message.html?m=1